# mysqldump command not found when Backing up MYSQL Database

Tags: raspbian, mysql

So I'm trying to turn my Raspberry pi into an automated MYSQL backup server but I'm struggling to find a working shell script to archive what I'm looking for. Until I came across this [Git Repo](https://github.com/gradus/mysql-backup) but when I try to run the script with all the correct credentials I am returned an error

```
mysqldump: command not found
```

This is regarding `mysqldump -h $HOST --user=$USER --password=$PASS $database > $BACKDIR/$SERVER-mysqlbackup-$database-$DATE.sql` on line `149` although I see no reason why this wouldn't work? Possibly someone else can. Except this, no errors are returned and the zip is created with the .sql file included but with no text. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: mysqldump is part of the mysql . mariadb client package. Is that installed?

Comment: @Dirk Ahhhh no it's not is there anything special to install or just MySQL?

Comment: Depends on Raspbian version. For Stretch mariadb-client and for Jessie mysql-client

Comment: @Dirk your a true legend :) <3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

mysqldump is part of mysql / mariadb client packages.
For Raspbian Jessie install package 'mysql-client', for Stretch you need 'mariadb-client'

Comment: Wouldn't the package depend on the DBMS one has installed, rather than Raspbian release?

Comment: No. mysql was replaced by mariadb in Stretch. mariadb is pretty much a plug-in replacement for mysql. I think there are actually some mysql meta-packages that will install mariadb